# How to use `setMockClassName` from phpunit with a class-string correctly?

Tags: php, phpunit

Recently, the maintainer of PHPUnit made a change to the "setMockClassName" method so that it now accepts only class-strings instead of regular strings. I'm currently handling this maintenance in the codebase I'm working on, but I'm struggling to implement these changes correctly. Some colleagues have suggested using an anonymous class (which was also my initial instinct), so I attempted the following:

```php
public function testSomeMethod(): void
{
    $anonymousClass = new class() {
    };

    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(MockClass::class)
        ->setMockClassName($anonymousClass::class)
        ->getMock();

    // Test assertions go here
}
```

However, this results in a `ClassAlreadyExistsException` being thrown.

So, I decided to define a separate class and use it as the class name:

```php
// This class is in the same directory, in "DumbClass.php"
namespace Org\Project\Package\Tests;

class DumbClass {
}



// This code is in "MyClassTest.php"
namespace Org\Project\Package\Tests;

final class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSomeMethod(): void
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(MockClass::class)
            ->setMockClassName(DumbClass::class)
            ->getMock();

        // Test assertions go here
    }
}
```

I'm running straight from the vendor (vendor/bin/phpunit) for simplicity purposes, this one throws a message with "ParseError: syntax error, unexpected namespaced name "My\Namespace\DumbC...", expecting identifier"

I've tried searching various forums, the PHPUnit issues, and StackOverflow, but I haven't found anyone else encountering the same issue. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks good, have you checked if both test classes are autoloaded properly?

Comment: From what I can tell, the classes are being correctly autoloaded. Also, I included the error from the second example.

Comment: Are you using a namespaced class for the mock object?

Comment: Yes, the test and the mock object are under the same folder too

Comment: can you try by explicitly mentioning the namespace at the top? like an example `namespace My\Namespace;`?

Comment: PHPUnit deprecated without any replacement a lot of mocking functionality. I suggest you to consider migrating to `Mockery` at least for the new tests. In my setup PHPUnit is a just a  runner, while `Mockery` is a mocking engine.

Comment: Regarding the issue, please post a minimal reproducible example in any public sandbox, e.g. `replit`.

Comment: Unfortunately, migration to Mockery is not possible at the moment for N reasons, but I'll take it in consideration! I tried to creating a reproducible example as well in replit but upon using composer it ask me for sudo permissions. @Adi, I added the namespaces!